# About the pronunciation of 시

Tags: pronunciation

Is the pronunciation of 시 same as "x" as in Mandarin ? It's sound similar to me, but I'm not sure if they are exactly the same. Do they have the same tongue position and mouth shape, having the same sound ?

Comment: what do you mean by x in Mandarin?

Comment: Click the speaker icon here to hear what it sounds like: https://papago.naver.com/?sk=ko&tk=en&st=%EC%8B%9C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost.

"x" in Mandarin refers to [Mandarin Pinyin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinyin), which points to the [voiceless alveolo-palatal fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_alveolo-palatal_fricative). In [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet), a comparison can be given as follows:

- Mandarin 「細」 (Pinyin: **xì**), Toneless IPA: **/ɕi/** ([audio sample](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/08/Zh-x%C3%AC.ogg))
- Korean (Seoul) 「시」, IPA: **/ɕʰi/** ([audio sample](https://papago.naver.com/?sk=ko&tk=en&st=%EC%8B%9C))

The difference between the two is that in Korean, at least in the Seoul standard, 「시」 is supposed to be pronounced with an [aspiration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirated_consonant), although I confess I can't really hear the difference.